# On a certain "anticurl" operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, de-rham-cohomology, curl

I recently found myself curious what explicit formula I would get if I traced through the de Rham cohomology proof that if $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has divergence 0, then $\mathbf{F}$ is the curl of some other vector field.  So, tracing through the proof, what I did starting with such a divergence-free vector field was:

- Convert $\mathbf{F}$ to a 2-form.
- Pull back along the contraction homotopy $H : \mathbb{R}^3 \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $(x, y, z, t) \mapsto (tx, ty, tz)$.
- Apply the integral operator $\mathfrak{I}$ which intuitively sends $dt \wedge \omega \mapsto \int_{t=0}^{t=1} \omega \, dt$ and for other $\omega$ without a $dt$, only with $dx,dy,dz$, $\omega \mapsto 0$.
- Convert the resulting 1-form back to a vector field.

After working through this, the formula I eventually got could be summarized as:
$$(\operatorname{anticurl} \mathbf{F})(\mathbf{x}) := \left[ \int_0^1 t \mathbf{F}(t \mathbf{x})\,dt \right] \times \mathbf{x}.$$
This has the expected property that $\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F} = 0 \implies \mathbf{F} = \operatorname{curl} (\operatorname{anticurl} \mathbf{F})$.  (And trying it out on for example $\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = (y^a z^b, 0, 0)$, I get $(\operatorname{anticurl} \mathbf{F})(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{a+b+2} (0, -y^a z^{b+1}, y^{a+1} z^b)$ which does have the expected curl.)

It is also interesting that this $\operatorname{anticurl}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and in addition it respects rotations about axes through the origin.

So now, what I was curious about was: this explicit partial inverse of curl seems like something that very likely would have shown up before.  If there's a standard name for it, that would be interesting to know, or otherwise it would be good to see an example usage of this formula in a textbook or other reference more on the introductory than research level.

Comment: As it often seems to happen, the "Related" side bar came up with some more useful links than the search that showed up while I was composing the question.  A couple selected links which look useful, though not quite answering the "terminology / reference request": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator?rq=1  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073159/showing-that-a-divergence-free-vector-field-is-curl-of-a-vector-potential?rq=1

Comment: The [Newtonian potential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_potential) $\mathcal{G}$ seems like it could be useful here. In particular, see WP's section on the [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Fields_with_prescribed_divergence_and_curl) with prescribed div/curl. (Note that their $\mathbf{C}$ is your $\mathbf{F}$.)

Comment: @Semiclassical The link you gave says that it requires $\mathbf{F}$ to vanish faster than $1/r^2$ at infinity, whereas my formula has no such restriction.  My question is on this formula specifically.

Comment: Nice way of presenting it. If I am not mistaken Will Jagy quotes in the 1st [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/81477/949989) you found three formulas from Spivak's book that look very much like yours.